# Ruby: String Comparison Issues

Tags: ruby, string

I'm currently learning Ruby, and am enjoying most everything except a small string comparason issue.

```
answer = gets()

if (answer == "M")  
    print("Please enter how many numbers you'd like to multiply: ")   
elsif (answer. == "A")  
    print("Please enter how many numbers you'd like to sum: ")  
else  
    print("Invalid answer.")  
    print("\n")    
    return 0  
end
```

What I'm doing is I'm using gets() to test whether the user wants to multiply their input or add it (I've tested both functions; they work), which I later get with some more input functions and float translations (which also work).

What happens is that I enter A and I get "Invalid answer."The same happens with M.

What is happening here? (I've also used .eql? (sp), that returns bubcus as well)

Comment: Always thought it was "bupkiss", but I suppose an official english spelling would be meshuggah.

Comment: I noticed you've asked 3 questions but haven't accepted any answers. I'm not saying you should accept mine, but you should accept somebody's if your problems got solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gets` returns the entire string entered, including the newline, so when they type "M" and press enter the string you get back is `"M\n"`. To get rid of the trailing newline, use `String#chomp`, i.e replace your first line with `answer = gets.chomp`.

Comment: Alright, thanks to everybody who suggested chomp.

Coming from other languages that don't do things like that (C#, VB.NET, C++, Python, etc.), that was a unexpected wall.

Comment: Since I can't edit a comment I'll say this as well. That also solves my diagnostic issue: it'd also print a newline after I printed what I had entered. Thanks for saying why!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Ruby is including the carriage return in the value.

Change your first line to:

```
answer = gets().strip
```

And your script will run as expected.

Also, you should use `puts` instead of two `print` statements as `puts` auto adds the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

your answer is getting returned with  a carriage return appended. So input "A" is never equal to "A", but "A(return)"

You can see this if you change your reject line to   print("Invalid answer.[#{answer}]"). You could also change your comparison to if (answer.chomp == ..)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used gets put I think if you hit enter your variable answer will probably contain the `'\n'` try calling `.chomp` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline when you check your answer...

```
answer == "M\n"
answer == "A\n"
```

Or chomp your string first: `answer = gets.chomp`